# ongoing integration of two git repos for a single project

Tags: git, web, bitbucket

Disclaimer: I understand Git, but am a novice with using it firsthand (managed teams that use it, but have only used it a handful of times).

I created a git repo when I joined current company and have been doing [server deployments using git from local](http://mikeeverhart.net/2013/01/using-git-to-deploy-code/) using separate branches to deploy to dev/stage/prod. This is all working as expected.

Our creative agency has been working with my company much longer than me (they designed and developed the theme, custom plugins, etc. for the site). They recently started doing some new work and informed me that they have their own repository (logically, they want to retain their repo for historical purposes).

My question: Is there a way that I can integrate their repo with mine? Maybe by deploying commits made to their master branch into a branch in my repo (e.g. dev, stage or feature branches)?

One flaw I see with this approach is how to handle getting my repos changes back to their repo. Is there a way I could manage that? Or is this a lost cause?

Everything I've searched references merging two repos, but I'd like to know if there's a way to keep both working separately.

Comment: You can perhaps use `git submodules` http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/03/git-submodules-workflows-tips/ or `subtrees` https://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/

Comment: I guess I assumed that submodules were used for "other" code (like 3rd party modules, community modules, web app core updates), whereas this is intended for the same code. Thoughts?

Comment: I suppose this creative company can be treated like a 3rd party, they have plugins etc. that would suit the needs for a submodule. I've worked with submodules for a while and it turned out ok. Our CI tools could checkout the submodule and we could package up the artificats for deploy with our main repository.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion but it's entirely up to you to implement this. And it might not be the only solution.

Let them keep their git repo but ask them to version it. (v1.0, v.2.0), probably using **git tag**. Ask them what's their stable most version (the one that is their master branch and not the develop branch).

Create a symlink from your repo to their stable branch, cloned somewhere in your company server.

Ask them to keep releasing new features and updating their master branch every time they make a big change.

This way you don't need to copy their repo. Get to keep your repo. And get to keep your branches on your repo that you can switch to production(master) and development(develop) based on your need.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but help me understand the symlink and why it needs to be on the company server. If I'm understanding it, you're suggesting that I could also: 1) create symlink for a local copy of my repo (that could stay on my "agencies-feature-branch" in my repo) so that; 2) connect to agency repo where that symlink resides (so that when they update agency master, I could pull that down into my symlink'd directory, which would then basically become edits in my repo's agencys-feature-branch); 3) I could then merge that branch when ready to deploy their changes. Is that the idea?

Comment: Also, curious why (other than best practice?) that they would need to use git tag on those versions.